# lavaan - number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I am trying to simulate some data and then fit the model to the same data using lavaan. This is how my code looks like:

```
model <- '
A =~ A1 + A2 + A3
A ~~ A
A1 | -1*t1
A2 | 0*t2
A3 | 1*t3
B =~ B1 + B2 + B3
B ~~ B
B1 ~~ A2
B2 ~~ A3
'

data <- simulateData(model, sample.nobs = 100)

fit <- cfa(model = model, 
            data = data)
```

However, it's not working. The model doesn't run and when you call `summary` on the `fit` object, all you get is starting values. When I run `warnings()`, this is what I get:

```
Warning messages:
1: In th[th.idx > 0L] <- TAU[, 1L] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In th[th.idx > 0L] <- TAU[, 1L] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
3: In th[th.idx > 0L] <- TAU[, 1L] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
4: In th[th.idx > 0L] <- TAU[, 1L] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
5: In th[th.idx > 0L] <- TAU[, 1L] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
6: In th[th.idx > 0L] <- TAU[, 1L] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
7: In th[th.idx > 0L] <- TAU[, 1L] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
8: In th[th.idx > 0L] <- TAU[, 1L] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
9: In th[th.idx > 0L] <- TAU[, 1L] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
10: In th[th.idx > 0L] <- TAU[, 1L] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
11: In th[th.idx > 0L] <- TAU[, 1L] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
12: In th[th.idx > 0L] <- TAU[, 1L] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
13: In lavaan::lavaan(model = model, data = data, model.type = "cfa",  ... :
  lavaan WARNING:
    Model estimation FAILED! Returning starting values.
14: In th[th.idx > 0L] <- TAU[, 1L] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

So I am wondering what am I doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for each categorical indicator, its first threshold will always be labeled `t1`.  So if these are all binary, then your syntax should work if you update the threshold labels.  Also, if you don't want your thresholds to be fixed to their parameter values, then treat them as starting values in your syntax (in which case they can still be freely estimated, but the starting values will be used as parameters when generating data).

```
model <- '
A =~ A1 + A2 + A3
A ~~ A
A1 | -1?t1
A2 | 0?t1
A3 | 1?t1
B =~ B1 + B2 + B3
B ~~ B
B1 ~~ A2
B2 ~~ A3
'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! This works! However, I would still like to ask a few follow-up questions to understand this better.

1) What is the role of the question mark in the syntax?




2) What is the role of the numbers before the question mark (-1, 0, 1)? I put different numbers here because I noticed that otherwise I get all the same values for A1, A2 and A3.

Comment: 3) I am trying to simulate specific correlations between B1 and A2 and B2 and A3 (e.g. `B1 ~~ .3*A2`) with `standardized = T` in the `simulateData` function. However, I'm getting an error message about how I should use better starting values. How can I determine which starting values should I use?

Comment: (1)  The `?` operator is similar to setting a fixed value with `*`, but instead of fixing, it is a starting value (and is thus still estimated).  (2)  Pick whatever thresholds you want.  (3) Try the `simstandard` package.